# Image overlay is flickering?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**** The truth is all these solutions work, just not with the project so I will re-pose the question, slightly differently ****

Essentially I have an image, which when someone moves their mouse cursor over it, it displays a div (which contains an image - aka play button). When they move they're cursor outside of the image, the play button disappears.

It works but if you move the curse over the play button it flickrs like mad, hence I must have my events mixed up somehow..

Thanks in advance for any help...

HTML

```
<div id="cont">
    <div id="art"  style= "position: absolute; left: 20px; top: 40px;">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://www.newmusicproducer.com/img/ic_play.png"></a>
    </div>
    <img src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000008744854-5sr588-large.jpg?d408275" alt="smile" id="imgSmile"></img>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#art').hide();             
    $('#imgSmile').mouseenter(function() {
        $('#art').show();
    });

    $('#imgSmile').mouseleave(function() {   
        $('#art').hide();
    });
});​
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tW68d/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This same effect could be achieved using just CSS:

```
<div>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://www.newmusicproducer.com/img/ic_play.png"></a>
</div>

div
{
 background-image:url('https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000008744854-5sr588-large.jpg?d408275');
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
}
div a
{
 position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:30px;
    display:none;
}
div:hover a
{
    display:block;
}
```

[**​-- SEE DEMO --**](http://jsfiddle.net/tW68d/11/)

---

**EDIT:** In case you need to use this multiple times on the same page with different link URLs, I've made a version which requires minimal HTML using a bit of jQuery to apply the rest:

```
<div class="play kirkbridge" data-playUrl="/myPlayUrl"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tW68d/16/

This might be a bit overkill though, it depends on your usage.

Comment: +1 Nice solution. Although it won't work in <IE8 if you need full browser compatibility.

Comment: @jamcoupe You're right IE7 is fine, my mistake. It definitely won't work in IE6 though.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It won't work on a Nokia 3210 either. If a user is using either of these technologies they shouldn't expect things to work correctly.

Comment: @Curt LOL I know :D Just making sure people have all the facts when deciding how to do something. The fact IE6 still has ~7% share means you can't totally ignore it yet. Unfortunately.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah that's very true!

Comment: I have chosen this answer, basically because it covers both the CSS and Jquery solution(s).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is mousing over the new image is causing mouseout on the original. Try using `hover()` instead, along with both elements as the selector.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#art').hide();
    $('#imgSmile, #art').hover(
        function() {
            $('#art').show();
        }, function() {
            $('#art').hide();
        }
    );
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tW68d/2/)

Comment: I get no flickering here in FF12 - what browser are you using?

Comment: Im using Chrome, but it has to work in all browsers, especially IE. CSS above example does work in IE9.

Comment: I've just tested in Chrome 18.0.1025.168 m and it doesn't flicker there either?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.on()` method,
 than set both element as selectors and use an event `(e)` checker like:

#### *[demo jsBin](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/tW68d/10/)*

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#art').hide();


    $('#imgSmile, #art').on('mouseenter mouseleave',function(e){
        if(e.type === 'mouseenter'){
            $('#art').show();
        }else{
            $('#art').hide();   
        }
    });

});
```

---

What I like the most is the use of the Ternary operator like:

```
$('#imgSmile, #art').on('mouseenter mouseleave',function(e){
    var et = e.type === 'mouseenter' ? $('#art').show() :  $('#art').hide();  
});
```

#### *[Demo with ternaly operator](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/tW68d/12/)*

---

You can use in your exact case just the `.toggle()` method:

```
$('#imgSmile, #art').on('mouseenter mouseleave',function(e){
    $('#art').toggle(); 
});
```

#### *[demo with .toggle()](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/tW68d/13/)*

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach:

http://jsfiddle.net/aramk/ZqVZ6/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var art = $('#art');
    art.hide();
    var updatePlayButton = function() {
        if (art.is(':visible')) {
            art.hide();
        } else {
            art.show();
        }
    }

    $('#cont').hover(updatePlayButton);

});​
```

I'd use a wrapping DIV, since when the button overlaps the smile image and your mouse is over it you lose focus from the smile image and it starts flashing. This will avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

can be done using CSS too, if thats a posibility.

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xasy4/

```
<div id="imgSmile">
     <div id="art">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://www.newmusicproducer.com/img/ic_play.png">
        </a>
     </div>
    </div>
```

**the css**

```
 #imgSmile
{
    background: url('https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000008744854-5sr588-large.jpg?d408275') no-repeat center Transparent;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
#imgSmile > #art
{
    position: absolute; left: 20px; top: 40px; opacity: 0;
}
#imgSmile:hover > #art
{
    position: absolute; left: 20px; top: 40px; opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/jqkBx/1/

Why dont you just use CSS for hover effects?

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <img src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000008744854-5sr588-large.jpg?d408275" alt="smile" id="imgSmile" />

  <div id="art" style="position: absolute; left: 20px; top: 40px;">
     <a href="#"><img src="http://www.newmusicproducer.com/img/ic_play.png" /></a>
  </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
#art{
    display:none;
}
#wrapper{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;        
}
#wrapper:hover #art{
    display:block;        
}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#art').hide();             
    $('#imgSmile').mouseenter(function() {
        $('#art').show();
    });
$('#art').mouseenter(function() {
        $('#art').show();
    });
    $('#imgSmile').mouseleave(function() {   
        $('#art').hide();
    });
});​
```

just add `#art` mouse enter event