# Java - Game code acts differently between Mac and Windows

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;



public class Game extends JFrame implements KeyListener
{
    private int charX;
    private int charY;

    public Game()
    {
        charX = 250;
        charY = 450;
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        addKeyListener(this);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }


    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getKeyChar() == 'a')
            charX-=5;
        else if(event.getKeyChar() == 'd')
            charX+=5;
        else if(event.getKeyChar() == 'w')
            charY-=5;
        else if(event.getKeyChar() == 's')
            charY+=5;
        if(charX > 485)
            charX-=6;
        else if(charX < 10)
            charX+=6;
        if(charY > 485)
            charY-=6;
        else if(charY < 30)
            charY+=6;
        repaint();
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event)
    {
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event)
    {
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(charX, charY, 10, 10);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Frame frm = new Game();
        frm.setVisible(true);
        frm.repaint();
    }
}
```

At school I use a Mac and at home I use a PC with Windows 10 on it. On the Mac this code tends to act different from the Windows version. In the Mac version things go as expected with the character (square) only moving a bit with each key press. On Windows however, if you press any direction (like d) the character will continue moving right even though it should only have been called once. Not only that but the frame constantly flickers when painting as well. So I was wondering why there was a difference between the versions between Mac and Windows and how I might go about fixing the flicker issue on Windows. I plan on adding in the keyPressed and keyReleased methods later so I don't think I'll have a bad time with that.

Comment: This might help with your flickering issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869548/image-flickers-on-repaint The flickering is common and the best strategy is to use a buffer image so that there is always an image on screen rather than deleting the scene before repainting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Key events differ between operating systems. Windows may rapidly create typed events when a key is down when Mac OS may create just one.

The solution is to use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead of key events, although you may have some luck finding a combination of `keyPressed` and `keyReleased` that work for both operating systems (would still suggest to just use key bindings).

Answer (score 2):

AWT can behave differently depending on the OS, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408820/what-is-the-difference-between-swing-and-awt):

> AWT is a Java interface to native system GUI code present in your OS. It will not work the same on every system, although it tries.